# On IIS when deploying an .NET MVC 4 application, where should the physical path point to

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, iis, iis-7

Ok, possibly a silly question, but when deploying an .NET MVC 4 application using the IIS server, where should indicate the physical path to? The parent directory? The controller directory? The view directory? I keep getting an error saying he resource cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory where your application's top-level `Web.config` file is. This, if you've got one, is the same folder as where your `Global.asax` file is.

Comment: hmm, guess that's not the issue since still getting a 'resource not found' error. Any ideas on what I could be? Some answers I searched mentioned that it could be caused due to an `HttpGet` above the method, but I definitely don't have that.

Comment: It's still the answer to your question, though. Perhaps you should be asking a different question...